# Java XMLStreamException, checking for missing end tag

Tags: java, xml, tags

in a given XML File, I need to check that each starting tag has an end tag

If an end tag is not found, I want to give an error msg with the line number and tag name

I managed to do so but the exception still shows in the console.. how can I only show the error msg?

sample xml file with staff end tag missing:

```
<company>
<staff>
        <name>john</name>
        <area>area1</area>
        <city>city1</city>
        <initials>js</initials>

</company>
```

code:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Stack;

import javax.xml.stream.XMLEventReader;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException;
import javax.xml.stream.events.StartElement;
import javax.xml.stream.events.XMLEvent;



public class trial {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, XMLStreamException {

    InputStream is = new FileInputStream("C:/Users/IBM_ADMIN/Desktop/comparison.xml");
    XMLInputFactory inputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
    XMLEventReader eventReader = inputFactory.createXMLEventReader(is, "utf-8");
    Stack<StartElement> stack = new Stack<StartElement>();
    while (eventReader.hasNext()) {
        try {
            XMLEvent event = eventReader.nextEvent();
            if (event.isStartElement()) {
                StartElement startElement = event.asStartElement();
                System.out.println("processing element: " + startElement.getName().getLocalPart());
                stack.push(startElement);
            }
            if(event.isEndElement()){
                stack.pop();
            }
        }catch(XMLStreamException e){

            System.out.println("error in line: " +e.getLocation().getLineNumber());
            StartElement se = stack.pop();
            System.out.println("non-closed tag:" + se.getName().getLocalPart() + " " + se.getLocation().getLineNumber());

            throw e;
        }
    }


}



}
```

Comment: you can return the string which you are printing in console. You can put your logic in a method and return the string instead of doing `throw e;`

Comment: Since you `throw e;`, in your `main()` the exception is uncaught and thus printed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Throwing an `Exception` in the `main()` method means that the JVM has to catch it if you did not do it yourself, and it most likely does not know what to do, so you see the error printed and possibly execution aborted. [Read about main() throwing errors here.](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/257174/how-does-the-jvm-handle-an-exception-thrown-by-the-main-method)

What you need is to simply comment out the line

`throw e;`

since you handle the exception already.